# I'm not sure if I'm using NSOperationgQueue's addOperationWithBlock incorrectly

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I've been using `NSOperationQueue`'s `addOperationWithBlock:` to run code in background threads, like so:

```
self.fetchDataQueue = NSOperationQueue()

for panel in self.panels {
    self.fetchDataQueue.addOperationWithBlock() {
        () -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
            //Background code
        }
    }
}
```

I'm concerned that I may be doing this wrong. I can't see a way that the fetch queue would be able to know when an operation is done, since there's no completion to call, and I'm not confident it's tracking activity across threads to make sure it's still going.

And the point of using this is so that I don't queue them up in single file and take much longer to process, and so I don't run them all at once and use too much memory.

EDIT: I'm aware that I don't need to be doing dispatch_async, but it's simply an example of some block-based code I may call which may do the same thing, or a web request which may get back after a delay.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code will run in a background block. If you are using a queue to make sure that one operation only starts when the next one is finished, you may be in trouble: The block that you happen to the NSOperationQueue has finished as soon as it has *dispatched* the background code to GCD, not when the background code has actually finished which may be much later.

Comment: So how can I inform NSOperationQueue that my operation is finished?